# Git :: A lot of untracked files

Tags: git

I've just added a new git repo on my machine and I've noticed an extremely messy `git status`. It's showing a bunch of files from my desktop, c:/, basically almost everywhere. It's going outside the project folder for some reason and I'm just flustered. I've ran `git clean -xf` to see if that cleaned up my git status and it has not.

If this is normal behavior, please let me know.

```
David@PERSONAL ~/Desktop/Code/projects/laraforum (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        ../../../../.VirtualBox/
        ../../../../.WebIde70/
        ../../../../.bash_history
        ../../../../.bash_profile
        ../../../../.bashrc
        ../../../../.codeintel/
        ../../../../.gitconfig
        ../../../../.hgrc
        ../../../../.ssh/
        ../../../../.vagrant.d/
        ../../../../AppData/
        ../../../../BullseyeCoverageError.txt
        ../../../../Contacts/
        ../../experiments/
        ../hyphenical/
        ../thecoremc/
        ../../../David Ponce              9.docx
        ../../../Development/
        ../../../Music/
        ../../../New Text Document.txt
        ../../../Passwords.txt
        ../../../Photoshop Tools/
        ../../../Recordings/
        ../../../desktop.ini
        ../../../laravel-blade.tmLanguage.txt
        ../../../question.PNG
        ../../../syudJMa.png
        ../../../~$vid Ponce              1.docx
        ../../../~WRL2005.tmp
        "../../../\302\265Torrent.lnk"
        ../../../../Documents/
        ../../../../Downloads/
        ../../../../Favorites/
        ../../../../IntelGraphicsProfiles/
        ../../../../Links/
        ../../../../Music/
        ../../../../NTUSER.DAT
        ../../../../NTUSER.DAT{bbed3e3b-0b41-11e3-8249-d6927d06400b}.TM.blf
        ../../../../NTUSER.DAT{bbed3e3b-0b41-11e3-8249-d6927d06400b}.TMContaine
00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
        ../../../../NTUSER.DAT{bbed3e3b-0b41-11e3-8249-d6927d06400b}.TMContaine
00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
        ../../../../OneDrive/
        ../../../../PUTTY.RND
        ../../../../Pictures/
        ../../../../Saved Games/
        ../../../../Searches/
        ../../../../Vagrantfile
        ../../../../Videos/
        ../../../../VirtualBox VMs/
        ../../../../_viminfo
        ../../../../coreessentials/
        ../../../../homestead/
        ../../../../ntuser.dat.LOG1
        ../../../../ntuser.dat.LOG2
        ../../../../ntuser.ini
        ../../../../website/
        ../../../../workspace/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I ran this inside of a clean installation of laravel. Here's the git ignore:

```
.env.*
/.idea
/vendor
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
composer.lock
composer.phar
```

I don't know if this is something wrong on my part or with the way I have git set up.

My project folder contains a clean laravel installation.

Edit: When I ran a git init in my project folder, the git status did not show all the untracked files outside of the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows, pop open a `cmd.exe`, and run

```
dir \.git /s /p
```

Now read the path of each folder it finds, and ask yourself if that `.git` folder really needs to be there.

Git allows you to `cd` into your project and run `git` commands. It seeks a `.git` folder in the current folder, and it then checks each parent folder, on up. (By contrast, Subversion requires a `.svn` folder in every committed folder, which is very unwieldy.)

Comment: The command didn't work. `Invalid switch - ".git".`

Comment: Fixed in the current answer